# Can too many static variables cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c++, static, stack-overflow

As far as I know, something such as `static int number = 5;` will get initialised once, and then able to be modified later. To keep its value, the memory can't then be free'd or it will have to initialise itself again, which would defeat the purpose of `static` anyway. Something such as this here is a good example of a use case without declaring a member variable of a class,

```
while (true){
    static bool windowOpen = false;
    
    if (windowOpen == false){
        windowOpen = true;
        OpenWindow();
    } 
}
```

If it were a non-static variable, that window would open endlessly. Its a dummy example because you can delcare the variable outside the loop, however in a  much larger code base it would be almost impossible to do this without static or a class. Now if you apply this all throughout the program, these variables are never free'd until the program finishes? If it were just a non-static variable it would be free'd out of the scope. Suppose that you then have multiple stack based arrays throughout the program that are marked as `static`, over time, this would build up and if that memory is not free'd it would make sense that this would cumulatively build up until it causes a stack overflow? My reservation for this would be that there should be no difference between a class member and static variables in this example, except that classes will go out of scope and the memory be free'd?

Comment: Static variables aren't stored on the stack, iirc. Also, by the nature that they are static, they would not build up over time.

Comment: If your static initalization involves recursiveness, it might be able to. Other than that, static variables are stored in a separate data segment. You could run out of heap space though, though this would require special circumstances.

Comment: Static variables are not stack or heap allocated? Oh well I did not know that, thanks! Also @ChrisMM I know that, I just mean the more control paths it reaches, the more stack variables created.

Comment: It makes more sense to define `static Window w=OpenWindow();` (for a suitable definition of that function).  It still gets initialized once when first encountered (via use of an internal flag very much like your `bool`), and the variable name refers to something useful rather than just a flag.